# cocos2dx access to the container

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

```
bool Role::isCollWithCollArea(COLL_STATE _collState){
    bool bFlag=false;
    TMXObjectGroup *collGroup=Role::getGameMap()->getObjectGroup("coll");
/**
 CCObject* obj=NULL;

 CCARRAY_FOREACH(coolGroup->getObject(),obj){
      CCDictionary* dic=(CCDictionary*)obj;
 **/
    Vector<Ref*>obj;

    for_each(obj.begin(),obj.end(),obj);{

        cocos2d::Map<std::string,ValueMap> dic=(ValueMap)obj;
```

Is that right to instead the `/**...**/` area with these three lines code below? Xcode said:

> No matching conversion for C-style cast from `Vector<cocos2d::Ref>` to'ValueMap

on this line `cocos2d::Map<std::string,ValueMap> dic=(ValueMap)obj;`. How to fix that?

Comment: did you mean to add obj to the dictionary? Currently you try to assign obj as the dictionary.

Comment: /**there are codes using cocos2dx2.15**/ I want to updata /**..**/area to cocos2dx3.2

Comment: A very old question that has been abandoned, I suggest it is closed as "unclear".